# How to make alert() when recaptcha is solved?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, grecaptcha

I want to execute a function (lets make `alert()`) at the time when recaptcha is solved by a user. When it is solved, the green tick appears.

It seems that it is possible only with the `grecaptcha.render()` function. Yes?

Example site where it should work:
https://tii.ai/rJBTt

Recaptcha documentation:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use Jquery to target the two states that recaptcha is in - the two are

the  uses aria-checked="true" or "false"

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //find the recaptcha span 
    var u = $('span[aria-checked]');
        if(u.val() == "true") {
            //the recaptcha was checked
            //do something
        }
})
```

Comment: Can you write code which makes `alert()` (when recaptcha becomes solved) on the example site link? For now I don't see anything useful or new in your answer. And anyway, recaptcha can't be solved at the `$(document).ready` event.

Comment: And that element is in `<iframe>` - so `$('span[aria-checked]')` won't find it. You should check practical results before answering.

Comment: It is not an answer!